# How can I find out a files “mime-type(Content-Type?)”? on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, content-type

Is there a way to find out the MIME-TYPE (or is it called "Content-Type"...) of a file in windows batch/PowerShell?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [File from source](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) or you can [get win32 binaries from here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)

Example from empty file:

```
COPY NUL >test.ext && "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\file" −-mime-type test.ext
```

Which will return this:

```
test.ext; text/plain
```

**Update:**

Also `-b` or `--brief` do not prepend filenames to output lines

`file -b −-mime-type test.ext` return only the mime-type: `text/plain`

Type `file --help` for more options

*Note: The sources are much more recent than the executable file kindly made available to us by GnuWin32.*

Answer (score 16):

While not directly in the Windows command prompt, a more modern approach is to use [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win). Once installed, run `git-bash` and the command `file path\to\file`. An example output might be:

```
TestFile.ico: MS Windows icon resource - 1 icon, 128x128, 32 bits/pixel
```

Alternatively, use the command `file -i path\to\file` which might give:

```
TestFile.ico: image/vnd.microsoft.icon; charset=binary
```

Comment: Thank you! At least I can get the mime types and construct an `mv` batch to fix the file extensions. Perhaps someone with more time can automate the process :)

Comment: Great answer. Didn't have to download anything as I had git installed.