# HTTP header parameter for File extension in API call

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is it possible to add the file extension into the HTTP header?

I have developed a program for sending a file using an API call.
The file will not be restricted to *.doc* or *.pdf*, it can be with *.exe* or *.zip* extension as well.

The file is successfully uploaded to the server but the file extension seems not correct, it's showing the file type as ***data***, while I'm expecting another file type.

Here down the sample code sources for the upload part:

```java
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://ServerName:Port/Anything/data");  //remote API URL 
String filepath = "C://User//test//";
String file1 = filepath.concat(file);
System.out.println("Sending the file");
FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(file1));  // take the file from directory 
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addPart("display_name", (ContentBody) bin)
        .build();
post.addHeader("filename", file1);  
post.setEntity(reqEntity);  // send via post method
```

Will the **FileBody** read the file extension as well?

Comment: not error code return from server, the file reached my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify the file type, aka *Mime Type*, you should use either of the 2 args or 3 args constructors of `FielBody` instead of the one-arg one you are already using.

It should be something as follows, depending on your file type:

```java
FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(file1), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
```

Comment: the problem still the same after i add in your code, any idea ?

Comment: @attack The idea is simple. You are responsible for providing "a file extension", not the system. No way around that.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - During the time i read the file, i also need to included the file extension as well ? is it something like that?

Comment: @attack Document yourself about *mime-types* and how HTTP file upload works (Particularly the *Content-Disposition* header). The file name is included by the HttpClient framework (as you can see from the sources) but the mime type is not inferred: is left to the caller to give one or a default binary will be used (and "data" will be detected on server side). I have already linked two questions on how to retrieve the mime-type. If you want to do a quick test, just use "image/png" and see what the server reports.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - if i want to do a quick check, where i shoulod put "image/png"?

Comment: @attack Edited my answer. Don't pollute tmarwen inbox with unsolicited notifications, either comment my answer or just take the effort to use Google.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the `Content-Disposition` header from the headers list using `(HttpServletRequest) request.getHeader("Content-Disposition")`. This will have the filename present in last as `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="file.ext"`.

From here you can extract the file type.

You can do it in way also:

```
String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(fileName);
if (mimeType.startsWith("text/")) {
    // It's a text.
}else if(mimeType.startsWith("image/")){
    // It's an image.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code for the, at the time of writing, three constructors of `FileBody` [on the relevant repo](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/trunk/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/entity/mime/FileBody.java).

```
public FileBody(final File file) {
    this(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, file != null ? file.getName() : null);
}

/**
 * @since 4.3
 */
public FileBody(final File file, final ContentType contentType, final String filename) {
    super(contentType);
    Args.notNull(file, "File");
    this.file = file;
    this.filename = filename == null ? file.getName() : filename;
}

/**
 * @since 4.3
 */
public FileBody(final File file, final ContentType contentType) {
    this(file, contentType, file != null ? file.getName() : null);
}
```

If you don't specify a `contentType` the default is `ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY`.
It is the content type that defines the "file type" as not every OS use the file extension for that purpose.

---

If you are running in a Linux system see [How can I find out a files “mime-type(Content-Type?)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227182/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-mime-typecontent-type) to retrieve the mime type of a file.
There is also a [Windows equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460177/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-mime-typecontent-type-on-windows).

Once you had the content type in `contentType`, use the right constructor: `new FileBody(new File(file1), ContentType.create(contentType));`.
You may want to add encoding information too, see [ContentType](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html).

---

You didn't specify what server you are running, but before going into the labour of detecting the mime-type of a file, you can do a quick test consisting in putting an hardcoded mime-type in the request.
Just construct the `FileBody` object as

```
FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(file1), ContentType.create("image/png"));
```

Comment: it's able to detect ASCII file but it's fail for others file type, any idea?

Comment: @attack Without a [mcve] and the server side code is hard to tell.